# Django ImportError: cannot import name 'settings' only when running manage.py test

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and recently inherited a project that has two main apps (`my_app` and `my_soc_app`), and has a directory structure similar to the one shown at the end of the post.

I'm trying to run the project's tests, and when I run `python manage.py test`, the tests under the main app `my_app` all run fine, but when it tries to run the tests under `my_soc_app` run, it fails while trying to do `from my_soc_app import settings` with the error shown below.

I can't figure out why it complains about that import *ONLY* when I'm trying to run the tests.

The imports in my_app/my_soc_app/my_soc_app/soc_app1/tests/test_soc_app1.py are:

```
import asyncio
from unittest import TestCase, mock
from uuid import uuid4

import aioredis
import asyncpg
from aiohttp.test_utils import setup_test_loop, unittest_run_loop

from my_soc_app import settings
from my_soc_app.auth.user import User
from my_soc_app.services import Tracking
```

**Error Output**

And the error I get when I run `python manage.py test my_soc_app` is:

```
$ python manage.py test my_soc_app
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: my_soc_app.my_soc_app.soc_app1.tests.test_soc_app1 (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: my_soc_app.my_soc_app.soc_app1.tests.test_soc_app1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/<...absolute.path...>/my_app/my_soc_app/my_soc_app/soc_app1/tests/test_soc_app1.py", line 9, in <module>
    from my_soc_app import settings
ImportError: cannot import name 'settings'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Background**

`my_app` is the base app of the project and has several sub-apps under it. This is where the main logic and the api are defined and implemented (accounts, services, etc.)

`my_soc_app` is a web socket service that runs in a separate container. Its main purpose is to receive high frequency updates from mobile clients of the app and to publish events to socket listeners (mainly the web portal/frontend).

I run `my_app` like this:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

And test it like this:

```
python manage.py test my_app
```

I run 'my_soc_app` like this:

```
cd my_soc_app && python run.py
```

And expect that it should be tested like this:

```
python manage.py test my_soc_app
```

The contents of ./manage.py are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_app.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django  # noqa
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And the contents of ./my_soc_app/run.py are:

```
from aiohttp import web

from my_soc_app import settings
from my_soc_app.app import get_app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = get_app()
    web.run_app(
        application,
        host=settings.BIND_HOST,
        port=settings.BIND_PORT,
    )
```

**Directory Structure**

The project's directory structure is below.

```
project/
  manage.py

  my_app/
    __init__.py

    settings/
      __init__.py
      my_app.py

    apps/
      __init__.py

      app1/
        __init__.py

        tests/
          __init__.py
          test_app1.py

  my_soc_app/
    __init__.py
    run.py

    my_soc_app/
      __init__.py

        settings/
          __init__.py
          my_soc_app.py

        soc_app1/
          __init__.py
          app.py
          views.py

          tests/
            __init__.py
            test_soc_app1.py
```

Comment: Looks like `my_soc_app` is NOT a Django app at all...

Comment: :eek: you're right :embarrassed: :) lol, I'm just beginning to work with this project, and I just assumed `my_soc_app` was a django app too, especially given that the handover instructions for testing just said run `python manage.py test`! So it looks like I need two separate testing steps, right? 1) `python manage.py test my_app` and 2) `cd my_soc_app && python -m unittest discover` (which I just tried and worked), or a variant of the sort. Is asking manage.py to pickup non-django modules' unit tests a big no no in Django? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Well, it might work if you can resolve the import error, but then you might break something else if the whole things was never designed to work as part of the django project itself. IOW it's hard to tell if that's worth the price without actually working on the project... At worse, you can always use a makefile to run both the django tests and `my_soc_app` ones from one single command.

Answer (score 0):

You should import your settings with `from django.conf import settings`